# PHP/Bootstrap - Dynamically Add Fields & Submit Form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im a bit lost and figured you guys might be able to help.  
**What I am trying to do:**
I have a form where the user will dynamically add fields and then I would like the user to submit that form and display the values on the next page. But the user has to select a dropdown to show the type of data they are submitting inside the text box. For example

```
--------------------------
- Drop Down -Text Box   -
--------------------------

--------------------------
-  INT        -    123   -
--------------------------
--------------------------
-  TEXT       -    ABC   -   +
--------------------------
```

After Form Submit:

INT - 123 
TEXT- ABC

Does anyone know how I could do this?

**My Code:**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="values">
                <label>Type:</label>
                <form method="post" action="values.php">
                    <div class="form-group multiple-form-group input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-btn input-group-select">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <span class="concept">int</span> <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="#int">int</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <input type="hidden" class="input-group-select-val" name="contacts['type'][]" value="int">
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" name="contacts['value'][]" class="form-control">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-add">+</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form>
                </div>
            </div>


<script>
(function ($) {
    $(function () {

        var addFormGroup = function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var $formGroup = $(this).closest('.form-group');
            var $multipleFormGroup = $formGroup.closest('.multiple-form-group');
            var $formGroupClone = $formGroup.clone();

            $(this)
                .toggleClass('btn-success btn-add btn-danger btn-remove')
                .html('–');

            $formGroupClone.find('input').val('');
            $formGroupClone.find('.concept').text('int');
            $formGroupClone.find('.input-group-select-val').text('int');
            $formGroupClone.insertAfter($formGroup);

            var $lastFormGroupLast = $multipleFormGroup.find('.form-group:last');
            if ($multipleFormGroup.data('max') <= countFormGroup($multipleFormGroup)) {
                $lastFormGroupLast.find('.btn-add').attr('disabled', true);
            }
        };

        var removeFormGroup = function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var $formGroup = $(this).closest('.form-group');
            var $multipleFormGroup = $formGroup.closest('.multiple-form-group');

            var $lastFormGroupLast = $multipleFormGroup.find('.form-group:last');
            if ($multipleFormGroup.data('max') >= countFormGroup($multipleFormGroup)) {
                $lastFormGroupLast.find('.btn-add').attr('disabled', false);
            }

            $formGroup.remove();
        };

        var selectFormGroup = function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var $selectGroup = $(this).closest('.input-group-select');
            var param = $(this).attr("href").replace("#","");
            var concept = $(this).text();

            $selectGroup.find('.concept').text(concept);
            $selectGroup.find('.input-group-select-val').val(param);

        }

        var countFormGroup = function ($form) {
            return $form.find('.form-group').length;
        };

        $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', addFormGroup);
        $(document).on('click', '.btn-remove', removeFormGroup);
        $(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu a', selectFormGroup);

    });
})(jQuery);

</script>
```

Comment: Please add your current code

Comment: @cmorrissey, I added my code. Now just trying to figure out how to take the values I entered with the dropdown value and pass them into the next page.